# What is the cryptogram in the ApplePay token?

Tags: ios, token, payment, applepay

I'm currently working on ApplePay and we are decrypting the token on our own server.

The decryption of token is done but there is a few things I don't quite understand. From the [Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf) we know that:

"The payment token encapsulates the
information needed to complete a payment
transaction, including the device-specific
account number, the amount, and a unique,
one-time-use cryptogram."

But from the [Payment Token Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929), there are 8 things contained in a token:

1. applicationPrimaryAccountNumber
2. applicationExpirationDate
3. currencyCode
4. transactionAmount
5. cardholderName
6. deviceManufacturerIdentifier
7. paymentDataType
8. paymentData

We get the accountNumber and the amount, but which one of those is the cryptogram?
Is it the last one, paymentData, since the other 7 really don't look like cryptogram? If not, how could we get this cryptogram?

I'd also like to ask what should we do after we get the cryptogram? Should we send the cryptogram and accountNumber to the acquirer?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you using to do the decryption?  I'm looking for a way to do this with an NPM package.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [Payment Token Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929)
You will see that the token contains a `paymentDataType` string and a `paymentData` dictionary.

If the paymentDataType is "3DSecure" then the paymentData dictionary will contain a key `onlinePaymentCryptogram` which is the cryptogram string.

This must be submitted to your payment gateway if you are submitting a 3-D Secure transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So If its EMV then we don't need this cryptogram? And the paymentData decrypted from the token is still encrypted. Can we decrypt this paymentData to get the cryptogram or send the encrypted paymentData to payment gateway directly?

Comment: That depends on your payment gateway - some can handle the decryption for you, others don't. Your best bet would be to talk to your gateway directly and see what they can support. Your gateway can also tell you which format they would prefer (3DS / EMV).